# stripe card token undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

Not able to process payments with stripe due to stripe card token undefined, tried a valid card number from https://stripe.com/docs/testing. Still does not work.

user.rb file:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
     # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
     devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

      belongs_to :plan

      attr_accessor :stripe_card_token

       def save_with_payment

          if valid?
           customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, card: stripe_card_token)
            self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
           save!

           end
           end

           end
```

routes.rb file:

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do

     devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'users/registrations'}
     resources :contacts
     get '/about' => 'pages#about'
     root 'pages#home'
     end
```

users.js file:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'));

    $("#form-submit-btn").click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);

     var error = false;
     var ccNum = $('#card_number').val();
     var cvcNum = $('#card_code').val();
     var expMonth = $('#card_month').val();
     var expYear = $('#card_year').val();

      if(!error) {

      Stripe.createToken({

     number: ccNum,
     cvc: cvcNum,
     exp_month: expMonth,
     exp_year: expYear

      }, stripeResponseHandler);

      }

       }); // form submission

       function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {

      var f = $('#new_user');

      var token = response.id;

      f.append('<input type="hidden" name = "user[stripe_card_token]" value="' + token + '" />');

      f.get(0).submit();

      }

      });
```

application.html.erb file:

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "https://js.stripe.com/v2/", type: 'text/javascript' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= tag :meta, :name => "stripe-key", :content => STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Comment: If you log the token to the console is it actually coming through in the JS?

Comment: Hi ruby_newbie, in the console I get the following error:  Started POST "/users" for 54.244.95.60 at 2016-06-15 22:59:44 +0000
Cannot render console from 54.244.95.60! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"CbuBs9QbmkAjPev5DuiXH75j5CgTng4KEWjOetnmCxmVXJubhSYG6De8ehvcRPRK9gFtG82NFuh8KJNsaU9ULg==", "plan"=>"2", "user"=>{"email"=>"test@outlook.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]
", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "stripe_card_token"=>"undefined"}}

Comment: The problem is the undefined - stripe_card_token

Comment: I mean console.log(response) in your JS